# Homemade dual USB hub

Tags: usb, usb-hub

Can I make a dual port USB HUB without a controller (parallel connection) it is only going to be used for a mouse and a keyboard. In other words will the Pc recognize them as 2 devices. Thanks

Comment: *Can I make a dual port USB HUB without a controller* You **can't**, USB needs a controller (a HUB) to split one connection into two. If you connect two USB clients (mouse, keyboard) in parallel to one USB host (PC) port, it will not work. **I guarantee it**

Comment: Why,I don't get it there aren't that much of data transferred

Comment: If you have two bricks, put them together and guess what... you still don't have a house.

Comment: Still didn't get it

Comment: Nothing to do with the amount of data, but "enumeration", and the fact that both devices will talk at the same time causing conflict.

Comment: *Why...?* The fact that not so much data (what is not so much anyway ?) is transferred is **irrelevant**. The USB connection follows a certain **protocol** this means that devices must take turns to use the connection. They devices (mouse, keyboard) cannot decide themselves when they can use the connection. The Hub decides that for them. USB is simply not made to connect things in parallel.

Comment: @TeckEgy. The amount of data isn't the problem here, but the *electrical and logical connections*. The USB protocol was built to expect one or no devices in each port. If it had more in the same connection, 1. they would electrically interfere with one another by dropping line impedance and 2. they would both try to respond at the same time. This was done to get more speed from a single connection. To allow more, it needs a hub to arbitrate data transfer

Answer (score 2):

USB interface circuits are designed as point to point with transceivers on each end. If you try to join or "direct wire" together two of them on one end of an interface the local transceivers will conflict with each other when trying to drive back to the computer. This problem is solved by using a USB hub which provides internal routing circuitry to allow the computer end of the interface to be fanned out to multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean simply soldering together two USB ports to make a "pigtail" then the answer is No, this will not work.  You must have active electronics to act as a hub allowing multiple devices to be enumerated.

Comment: I don't get it there aren't much of data transferred so why it needs a hub.

Comment: Huh? Why do you think that way? A hub doesn't magically increase throughput but instead, it *splits* existing throughput. But the reason you can't do this is simply the devices need arbitration so they aren't babbling on the same line at the same time. That's what the hub does.

Comment: @TeckEgy. - "there aren't much of data transferred". There is an old saying, "It's not what you don't know that will get you into trouble, it's  what you know that isn't so." Please keep that in mind and start doing some research on how USB works, particularly the address/data protocol. You obviously have no idea how USB data transfers work, and you need to learn. At the very least, look it up on Wikipedia, and read the WHOLE article and PAY ATTENTION. If you find your eyes glazing over, that is a sure sign that the subject is more complicated than you thought. You have done no research.

Comment: I found the book USB Complete by Jan Axelson greatly helpful in understanding the USB protocol.  Highly recommended.  But there's also a lot of great info for free on the web.